Sending data from Rails to get validated in JSON Schema
In my app I am sending product information in various types (string, integer, float, and boolean) for validation by a JSON Schema.
I noticed today when attempting to send false boolean values for validation by the JSON schema, that I was getting errors from my ruby validations. After removing the validations to isolate whether the issue was with my JSON schema or my model I discovered that any false value being sent to my JSON schema was being treated as empty data.
If I sent true to the JSON schema, it validates without issues and then if I re-enable my ruby model validations (such as requiring other information if those values are true) then everything works as intended.
If I enable my validation for my booleans:
validates :column, inclusion: {in: [true, false] }

Then my model will also yell at me if I try to send false values:
Validation failed: value1 is not included in the list, value2 is not included in the list

After searching online to try and find reasons why the false value is being seen as empty the only thing I can think of is some issue with how Rails is sending false value to JSON schema, and then JSON schema is discarding that information and sending neither true or false back to the ruby model.
Since the ruby validation is claiming that the false value is not in the list, but has no issues with the true value perhaps it is the fact that ruby will treat most things as true?
When creating a record in the console the validation also fails when trying to use false (not "false") because it says that the required value is not present.
I did try changing boolean values using a few different methods but none seemed to do the trick. My current version is:
  def convert_to_bool(value)
    return true if value == true || value.to_s.downcase == 'true'
    return false if value == false || value.to_s.downcase == 'false'

    value
  end

Edit:
The intended use of the app is to take information from a csv file and validate against a json schema using the gem activerecord_json_validator.
Since csv files values are sent as strings, I have found that I have to convert the values, since things like booleans will get sent as "true" and "false" instead of true and false.
With the convert_to_bool in place, I was able to get the values to change from "true" and "false" to true and false (according to my development logs) but when I require the values in the json schema I run into issues.
Since I was having the same issues whether I was using my csv or trying directly in the rails console, I am guessing the issue isn't with the string to boolean conversion, since as you said rails should send the proper value in the console when I am entering my information:
b = BagContainer.new
b.dynamic_attributes = {bladder_compatible: false, bladder_included: false, bladder_volume_l: 2}
b.valid?

and the information still comes up as invalid:
b.errors.full_messages

yields
["Dynamic attributes object at root is missing required properties: bladder_compatible, bladder_included"]

With the json schema being
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "bladder_compatible": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "bladder_included": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "bladder_volume_l": {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 1.5,
      "maximum": 3
    }
  },
  "required": ["bladder_compatible", "bladder_included"]
}

Having now used this schema in a few different validators it appears that there is nothing wrong with the schema. activerecord json validator uses json schemer and json schemer validates without issue.

What do you even mean by "Sending data from Rails to get validated in JSON Schema"? Are you using a gem that provides JSON schema validations in Rails? Sending it via HTTP to some service? The question is lacking any meaningful information to make it actually answerable and is mostly just about what you think the problem is (but may be a red herring).

Instead focus on giving us a complete picture with code that replicates the issue that you have. That booleean conversion method is completely unnessicary. Rails will cast boolean attributes automatically. If you really did need to do it manually use ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value).

My apologies, I should have notes in app's intended use any not just what I was trying to do to get things to work.

After combing through my code to check the dynamic_attributes values at every stage of validation I found out that they way in which I was removing any empty strings was also removing the false values due to how Ruby treats false values and my incompetence. I should have figured it out as soon as I realized my validation for presence on boolean values had to be changed to inclusions, I had to make the same change for empty strings. Lesson learned!
My original (incorrect) approach:
def remove_empty_strings
    return unless dynamic_attributes

    self.dynamic_attributes = dynamic_attributes.select { |_, v| v.present? }
  end

The new (seems to be working) approach:
def remove_empty_strings
    return unless dynamic_attributes

    self.dynamic_attributes = dynamic_attributes.reject { |_, v| v == '' }
  end

